How can I disable the astextplain attribute on git for windows?
I read What is the difference between diff and diff=astextplain? and understand what astextplain does and that it comes as part of a git for windows install, but I don't want it. How can I disable it per repo? Can I disable it globally on my PC?

Disabling for all users of a single repo
Looks like creating a .gitattributes in the root of your clone will disable it:
*.doc   -diff=astextplain
*.pdf   -diff=astextplain
*.rtf   -diff=astextplain

The - prefix removes that attribute. You can use git check-attr --all test.pdf to check the attributes on test.pdf and see that after adding this .gitattributes, it no longer sets astextplain.
That .gitattributes changes the diff behaviour for all other users of my repo and I don't think they can override these settings.
